# Update nested subdocument in Mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm trying to update a nested subdocument in Mongoose using ExpressJS, but I can't seem to get it working. The positional `$` operator does not traverse more than 1 level, and I've tried using `arrayFilters` but I can't seem to get that working either.

This is the document :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c52b017d9133d14876d2493"),
    "title" : "main_item",
    "subitem" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c52f4e74ef7482a646fc264"),
            "title" : "sub_item",
            "messages" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5303fa4b20df2d33d6eb08"),
                    "type" : "single_article",
                    "date" : "Jan 31, 2019",
                    "title" : "item",
                    "text" : "<p>item text</p>"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5c53040b4b20df2d33d6eb09"),
                    "type" : "single_article",
                    "date" : "Jan 31, 2019",
                    "title" : "item 2",
                    "text" : "<p>item 2 text</p>"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}

postController.updateMessage = function(req, res, item) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  var sub_id = req.body.sub_id;
  var saveData = {
    title: req.body.title,
    text: req.body.text
  };
  item.updateOne({'subitem._id': id}, {$set: {'subitem.$[el1].messages.$[el2]': saveData}}, {arrayFilters:[{"el1._id": id},{"el2._id": sub_id}]})
};
```

Mongoose model:

```
var submessages = mongoose.Schema({
  date: String,
  type: String,
  title: String,
  text: String
});

var subitems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  messages: [submessages]
});

var menuItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title : String,
  subitem: [subitems]
}, {collection: 'menu_items'});

module.exports = mongoose.model("menu_items", menuItems);
```

Comment: Can you please share your model(s). It may help in answering the question

Comment: I've edited it with my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I have an answer on how to exactly fix your problem, but I am going to recommend a solution that I think significantly increases the level of organization in your code...

**(1)** First and foremost, each of those schemas should be exported as separate models (and I would recommend them each be in separate files)

**(2)** Second, in your `subitems` and `menuItems` schemas, make the messages and subitems references. If you follow the first suggestion I made, then you can make your menuItems schema like follows:

**menuItems.js**

```
const menuItems = new mongoose.Schema({
  title : String,
  subitem: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'sub_items'
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("menu_items", menuItems);
```

Where `sub_items` is the name of your subitems model which you have exported. Use a similar format with your subitems model too, but I'll let you do that because I don't want to steal all the fun ;)

**(3)** Now that these are references, when you need to change a subitem that a menuItem references, you just need to update the actual subitem. You no longer need to update the subitem *through* the menuItem object, since the reference to the subitem never changes!

I hope this helps. It should be much more organized for you now, and should be **MUCH** simpler to updated your subitems and submessages

Comment: Thanx, that really helps :)

Comment: Do you know how I can post a subitem as a reference to each menu item? I am new to references, and I don't know how I can work with this