# findByIdAndDelete a subdocument with mongodb and mongoose, ( nodejs )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to delete a subdocument that i have in my very deep nested schema...

i am using findByIdAndUpdate method but it is not removing the subdocument.

i have this in my nodejs

//I pretend to delete a subdocument inside the array "items"

```
storeCtrl.deleteAlmacen = (req, res) => {
    storeModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id).then(() => {
        res.json('deleted')
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.json(err)
    })
}
```

And it is my schema

// i did not copy and paste, so maybe has some syntax errors

```
 {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c6cd20f13f0940e0cc214c5"),
            "store" : [
                    {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5c6cd20f13f0940e0cc214c6"),
                            "office" : [
                                    {
                                            "_id" : ObjectId("5c6cd21f13f0940e0cc214c8"),
                                            "items" : [
                                                    {
                                                            "_id" : ObjectId("5c6cd22e13f0940e0cc214cb"),
                                                            "pen" : "3",
                                                            "paperId" : "a4"
                                                    }
                                            ],
                                            "employees" : [ ],
                                            "work" : 1

                                    }
                                      ]
                     }
                      ]
    }
```

Do i have to use other method instead findByIdAndDelete?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this solution: [Update nested subdocument in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516428/update-nested-subdocument-in-mongoose/54520117#54520117)

Long story short, you should be using separate models, all of which reference each other. It's going to be a pain to change what you have now, but in all reality it's going to be MUCH cleaner.

You should have a `Store` model that references `Office` and an `Office` model that references an `Items` model

Comment: i have been thinking in that solution... but i thought that creating subdocuments was the "correct way"... i will try it,

Other question... how i should do the references between models?